# How come the loop is still true even though I haven't clicked the full length of the pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I'm doing an online course where my task is to code a Simon game in JavaScript. My code works but I can't get my head around why the loop in the checkAnswer function is true on a new level even though it hasn't got the full length of my pattern.

EX
**Level 1**

```
const gamePattern = ['blue'];
```

*I click blue*

**Level 2**

```
const gamePattern = ['blue', 'red'];
```

*I click blue.* And the loop checks if the `userClickedPattern` is the same. But here I haven't clicked the second color yet and the loop is still ok with that. What do I not understand about loops?

And here is my code.

```js
"use strict";

// Declared Variables
const buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
let userClickedPattern = [];
const gamePattern = [];
let level = 0;

// Plays the sound of the input color
function playSound(name) {
  const sound = new Audio("/sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  sound.play();
}

// Function that randomly selects the next color to be clicked
function nextSequence() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  const randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];

  $("#" + randomChosenColour)
    .fadeOut(100)
    .fadeIn(100);

  playSound(randomChosenColour);

  level++;

  // Updates the level text
  $("h1").text(`Level ${level}`);
  return gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
}

// User click function
$("div[type='button']").click(function(e) {
  const userChosenColour = e.currentTarget.id;

  playSound(userChosenColour);

  // Makes the button greyed out when clicked
  function animatePress(currentColour) {
    $("#" + currentColour).addClass("pressed");

    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#" + currentColour).removeClass("pressed");
    }, 100);
  }

  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
  animatePress(userChosenColour);

  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern);

  return;
});

// Runs once to start the game
$(document).keypress(function() {
  if (level === 0) {
    // Runs the nextSequence
    nextSequence();
  }
});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
  for (let i = 0; i < currentLevel.length; i++)
    if (gamePattern[i] !== currentLevel[i]) {
      $("h1").css("color", "red");
      $("h1").text("GAME OVER");

      return;
    }

  if (currentLevel.length === gamePattern.length) {
    setTimeout(nextSequence, 1000);
    userClickedPattern = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your issue?

Comment: What do you mean? The code works. Just that I don't understand why the loop is still true with only one color clicked.

Comment: It's not the loop. Think about how often it's been called.

Comment: Also consider this, IIRC Simon has a time limit for entering the pattern. Now this may not be a requirement for the assignment, but thinking about it might lead you to some insights.

Comment: Also: be consistent.  Either pass both arrays as parameters or pass none.  They are both global. Personally I'd avoid using globals.  Also, be more descriptive with parameter naming: *checkAnswer(currentLevel)* is not as informative as *checkAnswer(userPattern)*. Write code with the next programmer in mind that might have to decipher what you wrote.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Is it that the "userPattern.length" in
  for (let i = 0; i < userPattern.length; i++)

so if the userPattern.length only is 1 in length after one click but the gamePattern.length is 2 it doesn't matter because the loop only compares the userPattern[0] with the gamePattern[0] and runs once

Comment: Yes, without a timeout you are checking the answer on each color click against the length of the user input *at the time* which is why it succeeds, not the current game level limit, which would fail.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Where do you suggest I put the arrays if they shouldn't be global. And I don't understand what you mean with "Either pass both arrays as parameters or pass none."

Comment: This code is not very clear. Mix of globals, indentation not always consistent, mix of game logic with input/output concerns, ...etc. Not surprised you get lost with it. Maybe consider splitting game logic from input/output concerns as much as possible, and avoiding globals as much as possible.

Comment: @LuckyTiger: You are just beginning so don't worry about the problems with globals right now.  What I mean is do this: *checkAnswer()* or this *checkAnswer(userPattern, currentLevelPattern)*.   The latter is more clear.

Comment: Also consider that there is a difference between *checking the user answer* versus *has the user completed the input sequence*. You really should not check the answer before that.

Comment: @fnostro Thank you for the help I will think about the consistency in the future :)

Comment: yvw.  And congrats, you've just discovered that computers do EXACTLY what we tell them to do :) Happy coding!